# Unable to split using explode containing two hyphen

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

```
$str = "SC - ESV Parndorf 2 - 5 SV Horn";
$str4 = explode(" - ", $str,2);
$str5=$str4[0];     
$str6 = explode(" ", $str5);
$Num=end($str6);        
$str7=$str4[1];     
$str8 = explode(" ", $str7);
$Num1 = $str8[0];
```

Unable to get number 2 and 5 out of the string if I have two "-".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question accordingly. You may also want to check out the site tour to learn more about how things work around here.

Comment: I want to extract just scores.

Comment: Answer was helpful but......"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

For such a job, you'd better use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$re = '/(\d+)\s+-\s+(\d+)/';
$str = 'SC - ESV Parndorf 2 - 5 SV Horn';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
    (\d+)   : group 1, 1 or more digits
    \s+-\s+ : a dash between some spaces
    (\d+)   : group 2, 1 or more digits
/           : regex delimiter
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2 - 5
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
)
```